# No css displaying into my pages even with the files into the public folder

Tags: laravel

I put my css files into the `public\assets\css` folder, and into my view I'm doing this :
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/admin/article/admin_ajouter_article.css') }}">`

When I go to `localhost` and do `inspect`, I've this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/index/index_site.css">`

Does someone know why I've no css displaying please ?

Cordially

EDIT: Into the console I've this : `localhost/:21 GET http://localhost/img/logo_no_text.png 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update the path to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/admin/article/admin_ajouter_article.css') }}">
```

because [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset) function start looking from `public` folder not `assets`

> **Note**: if it still not showing your style after updating the **path** clear your browser cache by click `ctrl + shift + R` inside your browser